# Toggling an attribute on a ReactJS MaterialUI FloatingButton on click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to simulate a checkbox behavior with a FloatingButton. The buttons initially load with the secondary attribute set to true. Like so:

```
<FloatingActionButton secondary={true} mini>
    T
</FloatingActionButton>
```

If clicked, it toggles the secondary attribute value to false, Like this:

```
<FloatingActionButton secondary={false} mini>
    T
</FloatingActionButton>
```

Here is the end result with M being activated 
[image]

Here is what I tried to do, but of course, it's not working, lol

```
class PlayerNetwork extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activeDayId: "true",
        };
        this.setActiveDay = this.setActiveDay.bind(this);
    }

    setActiveDay(id) {
        this.setState({activeDayId: id});
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <FloatingActionButton
                            secondary={this.state.activeDayId === 1 ? "true" : "false"} 
                            mini
                            onClick={() => this.setActiveDay(1)}>
                            S
                        </FloatingActionButton>
                    </Col>
               <Row>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If you have a simpler, minimal-er way than mine, I'm all up for it as well. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: `secondary` prop expect boolean and you are passing string to that. So remove quotes `this.state.activeDayId === 1 ? true : false`

Comment: @Prakashsharma Awesome catch! However, it only toggles once. I need it to toggle instead of swap. Also wen I take the string quotations off it throws an error for an unnecessary ternary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle the button then just put a condition in the method which checks that if id is already set then reset it

```
setActiveDay(id) {
        if (id === this.state.activeDayId) {
          // id is already selected and user has clicked on it again so reset it by assigning "null" to it
          this.setState({activeDayId: null});
        }
        else {
           this.setState({activeDayId: id});
        }
    }
```

Also you can pass boolean to `secondary` prop without using ternary operator like this

```
<FloatingActionButton
    secondary={this.state.activeDayId === 1} 
    mini
    onClick={() => this.setActiveDay(1)}>
         S
</FloatingActionButton>
```

**Update:**

If you want to keep track of multiple days then you have to take an array. Initialize array in `constructor` which keeps track of active days

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {
     // initially blank, so no days are active
     activeDayIds: [],
  }
}
```

then change `setActiveDay` to this

```
setActiveDay(id) {
        let activeDayIds = [...this.state.activeDayIds];
        if (this.state.activeDayIds.includes(id)) {
          // id is already in the array which means it is selected and user has clicked on it again so remove it from array
          activeDayIds.splice(activeDayIds.indexOf(id), 1);
        }
        else {
           // this id is not in the array yet which means user has activated this so include this in array
           activeDayIds.push(id)
        }
       // set back the state
       this.setState({activeDayIds: activeDayIds});
    }
```

and then render the element with following condition

```
<FloatingActionButton
        secondary={this.state.activeDayIds.includes(1)} 
        mini
        onClick={() => this.setActiveDay(1)}>
             S
    </FloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: This solved the toggle. But I can only keep one on now. When I toggle another, it changes the toggle state on the other. Maybe I went about this all wrong from the beginning. The user should have any day on or off he chooses. To give you an idea, it's a player that he's choosing what days it should run. Could be all, could be only one day, Could be 3. I apologize if my code confused you.

Comment: Can this be done simpler? Instead of IDs, toggle the state on click, regardless of ID? I went with IDs because I was trying to avoid repeating the function seven times. Each day should work independently.

Comment: Aweomse! Thats it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the `true` and `false` values are wrapped with quotes, they'll be always `true` values.

So as you have `{this.state.activeDayId === 1 ? "true" : "false"}`
in your `secondary` prop, it will be always `true`

Try it it without quotes, like:

```
<FloatingActionButton
  secondary={this.state.activeDayId === 1 ? true : false} 
  mini
  onClick={() => this.setActiveDay(1)}>
    S
</FloatingActionButton>
```

Or more simply:

```
<FloatingActionButton
  secondary={this.state.activeDayId === 1} 
  mini
  onClick={() => this.setActiveDay(1)}>
    S
</FloatingActionButton>
```

Comment: I like your simpler way. That's good. But the button only toggles once. What am I missing?

Comment: I think in your example you always set the id to 1 and not toggle it. Do you have seven `FloatingActionButton` components for the 7 days? If yes, each `FloatingActionButton` should have a unique id and the `onClick` action should set the given `FloatingActionButton` id in the state.

Comment: I tried that but only one toggle stays on. I need all days to work independently without building 7 functions